# Публикация на MavenCenter

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Никак не могу понять почему не видит мой репозиторий

gradle репозитория

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

ext {
    groupId = 'com.io'
    artifactId = "testLib1"
}

apply from: rootProject.file('publishing.gradle')
```

зависимость в главном gradle

```
apply plugin: 'io.codearte.nexus-staging'
```

мой publishing.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'

ext["signing.keyId"] = ''
ext["signing.password"] = ''
ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = ''
ext["ossrhUsername"] = ''
ext["ossrhPassword"] = ''

File secretPropsFile = project.rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (secretPropsFile.exists()) {
    Properties p = new Properties()
    p.load(new FileInputStream(secretPropsFile))
    p.each { name, value ->
        ext[name] = value
    }
} else {
    ext["signing.keyId"] = System.getenv('SIGNING_KEY_ID')
    ext["signing.password"] = System.getenv('SIGNING_PASSWORD')
    ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = System.getenv('SIGNING_SECRET_KEY_RING_FILE')
    ext["ossrhUsername"] = System.getenv('OSSRH_USERNAME')
    ext["ossrhPassword"] = System.getenv('OSSRH_PASSWORD')
}

def getArtifactFilePath() {
    return "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar"
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            releaseAar(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = project.ext.groupId
                artifactId = project.ext.artifactId
                version = rootProject.ext.versionName
                artifact getArtifactFilePath()

                pom {
                    name = 'DebagLog'
                    description = 'TestApp'
                    url = 'https://gitlab.com/Privatik/publishtest'

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                            url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id = 'Privatik'
                            name = 'Ivan Ivanov'
                            email = 'privatikk@gmail.com'
                        }
                    }

                    scm {
                        connection = 'scm:gitlab.com/Privatik/publishtest'
                        developerConnection = 'scm:git:ssh://gitlab.com:Privatik/publishtest.git'
                        url = 'https://gitlab.com/Privatik/publishtest'
                    }

                    withXml {
                        def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                        project.configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "mavencentral"
                url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
                credentials {
                    username ossrhUsername
                    password ossrhPassword
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

nexusStaging {
    packageGroup = project.ext.groupId
    stagingProfileId = '111111111111'
    username = ossrhUsername
    password = ossrhPassword
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications
}
```

пробую залить этой командой

```
gradle testLib1:publishReleasePublicationToSonatypeRepository
```

Но получаю всегда такую ошибку

```
Task 'publishReleasePublicationToSonatypeRepository' not found in project ':testLib1'
```

И не могу никак понять почему?

Comment: И где здесь ошибка про репозиторий? Запустите `gradle testLib1:tasks` и посмотрите что за имя таска для публикации вам плагин добавил.

Comment: Хочу у вас ещё спросить может сталкивались Unable to read secret key from file: C:\Users\Android dev\AndroidStudioProjects\TestLib\secring.gpg (it may not be a PGP secret key ring)

Comment: Что ему не нарвится